springdoc-openapi-ui doesn't work with an application using Spring 6 and not Spring Boot
Recently, I have upgraded my application from Spring 5 to Spring 6. I am not using Spring Boot in my application due to legacy issues.
For API documentation, I was using SpringFox earlier but after migrating to Spring 6, I found that the latest version of SpringFox is not compatible with Spring 6. Also, SpringFox is not being maintained and we should migrate to SpringDoc.
I followed the steps mentioned here: How to Integrate Open API 3 with Spring project (not Spring Boot)? but I got the following error:
Error
Upon further analysis, I found that the class LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer is present in spring-core jar of Spring version 5 and not present in Spring 6.
Can anyone help me how to resolve this issue? Or are there any different steps on how to integrate SpringDoc with a non Spring Boot application which is using Spring 6?

I have the exact same issue. Any progress on that ?

I had to move to SpringDoc. It is compatible with Spring 6.
